# Changed Secure and Unsecure to HTTPS - Google Webmaster Tools now showing me Soft 404's

Tags: url-rewrite, https, secure

We wanted our entire website to be SSL secure so we changed secure and unsecure settings to HTTPS.  That works fine.

Google webmaster tools is now seeing some soft 404's that I'd like to fix.

But our web server rewrites that go from http://mainsite.com/catalog/category/view/id/74 to http://mainsite.com/CATEGORYNAME/INTERESTINGPRODUCTNAME.html are now getting in the way of writing redirects from the previously unsecured pages to the new secured pages.

GWT is detecting links that go to the previously unsecured  (which now just redirects to my secured homepage) and I need them to redirect to the secured  .

Did I set up my site's HTTPS secured settings incorrectly or is there a better way to set up soft 404 redirects?

Comment: Your server configure for port 80 and 443 should exactly the same, excerpt the ssl part. You should write down your server configuration for more detail that people can help.